# How to attach one spatialite database to another in db manager

Tags: qgis, database, dbmanager

I'm trying to attach one database to another so that data from it can be used in queries.

I'm using

ATTACH DATABASE '{full url}' AS {database_name};

No errors actually occur, but when I run

PRAGMA database_list

Only the main database shows.

Comment: And if you query the attached database?

Comment: @HeikkiVestano I get 'no such table' type errors.

Comment: And you're using "database_name"."table_name" in the query?

Comment: @HeikkiVesanto Yes

Comment: Does it work fine in the spatialite-gui? https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/spatialite_gui/index

Comment: @HeikkiVesanto No, here it returns "SQL query returned an empty ResultSet:This is not an error", but the database being referred to is not empty and functions perfectly well.

Comment: Oddly, trying a second time yielded "SQL logic error or missing database"

Comment: "SQL query returned an empty ResultSet:This is not an error" is the expected result. The PRAGMA database_list should still show it. But I think the non-working in the QGIS DBManager is a bug. Might be worth reporting. https://issues.qgis.org/projects/qgis/issues

Comment: @HeikkiVesanto Thanks. I've carried out the whole operation within sqlite-gui, and in another standalone sql gui. It's not adding it to the database list in any of them. I'm obviously doing something wrong, but I just can't seem to trace what it is.